# Show these two sets are equal

Tags: number-theory

Let $A:=\{4k+1:k\in \mathbb N\}$, and let $B:=\{4k+3:k\in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}\}$.

I need to show that the product of any element of $A$ with any element of $B$ is precisely the set of composite numbers of $B$.

Suppose $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $ab=16mn+12m+4n+3=4(4mn+3m+1)+3\in B$
for some $m\in\mathbb N$ and $n\in\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$

The product is an element of B and is clearly composite as $1\notin A,1\notin B$.
Just not sure how to show the products produce all composite numbers in $B$. Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b\in B$ be composite. Then $b=km$ for some integers $k,m>1$. Then $k,m$ are odd because otherwise $b$ would be even. So $k,m\in A\cup B$. If $k,m\in A$, then $km\in A$. If $k,m\in B$, then $km\in A$. We conclude that one of $k,m$ is $\in A$ and the other $\in B$.